# Adding many structs to a data structure (lvalue required as unary '&' operand)

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I have a function that creates and returns a node, which I plan to add to a hash table:

```
HashTableNode CreateNode(char* url){
    HashTableNode new;
    new.url = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(url) + 1));

    strcpy(new.url, url);

    return new;
}
```

I am trying to add many of these nodes to a hash table, but I have ran into a problem:

```
AddToHashTable(&lookup_table, &CreateNode(result));
```

gives me an error (lvalue required as unary '&' operand). I believe that this happens as the struct I am returning does not have an associated address in memory. For testing some of the functionality, I could assign several nodes manually and add those to the hash table, but clearly this solution won't scale well.

I have tried returning a pointer to a node instead in my CreateNode function:

```
HashTableNode* CreateNode(char* url)
{
    HashTableNode new;
    new.url = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(url) + 1));
    strcpy(new.url, url);
    return &new;
}
```

but instead I get a warning telling me I am returning address of a local variable.

Is there a way to assign a large amount of structs to the table without first assigning them to variables?

Comment: Is `HashTableNode` defined as `typedef` for some struct?

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>You are returning a local object `new`, which *lifetime* ends, when `CreateNode` function definition encounters `}` punctuator (i.e. it ends). It is *undefined behavior* to read such object from the outside.</strike>

Instead, define `CreateNode` as:

```
HashTableNode* CreateNode(char* url)
{
    HashTableNode *new = malloc(sizeof(*new));

    // new->url...

    return new;
}
```

This also solves your trouble with `AddToHashTable` call, as you already have a pointer of `HashTableNode*` type:

```
AddToHashTable(&lookup_table, CreateNode(result));
```

It is also recommended practice to always check result of `malloc` function, as it might fail someday.

Comment: In this design, the `AddToHashTable` function should accept a pointer, and take over ownership of that pointer.  Another possible design would have been to pass a node by value, and `AddToHashTable` would allocate a copy as it sees fit.